# Consuming JSON data with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am following along with the spring.io tutorial on [consuming a RESTful web service] with Spring Boot [1](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/).

In the tutorial, it provides an example with the following JSON data:

```
{
   type: "success",
   value: {
      id: 10,
      quote: "Really loving Spring Boot, makes stand alone Spring apps easy."
   }
}
```

It then provides the following class:

```
package com.example.consumingrest;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Quote {

  private String type;
  private Value value;

  public Quote() {
  }

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
  }

  public Value getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(Value value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Quote{" +
        "type='" + type + '\'' +
        ", value=" + value +
        '}';
  }
}
```

and states that "to directly bind your data to your custom types, you need to specify the variable name to be exactly the same as the key in the JSON document returned from the API."

The JSON data I am trying to pull is in the following format:

```
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2020-05-08",
        "4. Output Size": "Compact",
        "5. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },"Time Series (Daily)": {
    "2020-05-08": {
        "1. open": "122.6700",
        "2. high": "123.2300",
        "3. low": "121.0600",
        "4. close": "122.9900",
        "5. volume": "5002450"
    },
    "2020-05-07": {
        "1. open": "122.9800",
        "2. high": "123.2600",
        "3. low": "120.8500",
        "4. close": "121.2300",
        "5. volume": "4412047"
    }
}
```

My question is, how do I setup my get and set methods within the class if the data is not constant? Again, the tutorial states "you need to specify the variable name to be exactly the same as the key in the JSON document returned from the API."

Sorry if this is confusing. I'm still learning Spring Boot so I might be missing something very easy.

Please let me know if there is anything I can add for clarity.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-mapping-dynamic-object might give some guidance, but you'd need to treat it as dynamic and probably just a standard string string map Vs a named class

Comment: That is weird JSON. Especially the keys of the key-value pairs are weird, and they cannot be mapped easily to fields in a Java class. The normal mapping to Java objects that Spring Boot does will not be able to parse this, you'll need to parse this JSON yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is not constant then you can consume it either in the form of JSON object or String instead of directly mapping to any Class type object

**Accepting as String**

```
@PostMapping("/getData")
    public List<DataList> getDataList(@RequestBody String request) {
}
```

**Accepting as JSON Object**

```
@PostMapping("/getData")
    public List<DataList> getDataList(@RequestBody JSONObject content)
            {
}
```

Once getting String , it can be converted to **JSON Object** .

```
JSONOBject reqObj = new JSONObject(request);
```

then use **get method of JSONObject** to fetch any property

```
String field1 = reqObj.get("fieldName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using map with @RequestBody, something like:

```
@RestController
    public class Controller {
       @PostMapping
       public void postWithMap(@RequestBody Map<String, Object> requestMap) {
            // do something with the map..
       }
}
```

but if possible I'd try to rework the request so that uses collections for the time series, something like:

```
{
  "Meta Data": {
    "Information": "Daily Prices (open, high, low, close) and Volumes",
    "Symbol": "IBM",
    "Last Refreshed": "2020-05-08",
    "Output Size": "Compact",
    "Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
  },
  "Time Series (Daily)": [
    {
      "date": "2020-05-08",
      "open": "122.6700",
      "high": "123.2300",
      "low": "121.0600",
      "close": "122.9900",
      "volume": "5002450"
    },
    {
      "date": "2020-05-07",
      "open": "122.9800",
      "high": "123.2600",
      "low": "120.8500",
      "close": "121.2300",
      "volume": "4412047"
    }
  ]
}
```